# why the object is vector?

Tags: r

```
> x=c(1,2,3,4,5)  
> x1=list(n1=1,n2=2,n3=x)  
> is.vector(x1)
```

[1] TRUE

```
> is.list(x1)
```

[1] TRUE

why is.vector(x1)=true?i can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector in R is an ordered collection of stuff. Stuff in this case is

```
> mode(x1)
[1] "list"
```

from the help file

is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names.

```
> attributes(x1)
$names
[1] "n1" "n2" "n3"
```

if we were to give x1 another attribute:

```
levels(x1)<-1:3

> x1
$n1
[1] 1

$n2
[1] 2

$n3
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

attr(,"levels")
[1] 1 2 3

> is.list(x1)
[1] TRUE

> is.vector(x1)
[1] FALSE
```

it would still be a list but not now a vector

From [A brief history of S](http://cm.bell-labs.com/stat/doc/94.11.ps) "The basic data structure in S is a vector of like­elements: numbers, character strings, or logical val­ 
ues. Although the notion of an attribute for an S object wasn't clearly implemented until the 1988 release, 
from the beginning S recognized that the primary vector of data was often accompanied by other values that 
described special properties of the data. For example, a matrix is just a vector of data along with an auxil­ 
iary vector named Dim that tells the dimensionality (number of rows and columns). Similarly, a time series 
has a Tsp attribute to tell the start time, end time, and number of observations per cycle. These vectors 
with attributes are known as vector structures, and this distinguishes S from most other systems."

Presumably it is similar in R which is an implementation of S so these vector structures are not designated as vectors.

Answer (score 3):

From `?is.vector`

> If mode = "any", is.vector may return TRUE for the atomic modes, list and expression.

You can specify the `mode` if you do not want `is.vector` to return `TRUE` for a `list`

```
> is.vector(x1, mode='numeric')
[1] FALSE

> is.vector(x, mode='numeric')
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> is.atomic(x1)
[1] FALSE
```

From the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#List-objects), lists are *generic vectors*, but not *atomic vectors*.