# Why does list() return a vector, and not a list?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why the object is vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597175/why-the-object-is-vector)

Please see my code:

```
> x=function(z){z+1}  
> y=list(n1=1,n2="qwe",n3=TRUE,n4=x)  
> is.vector(y)

[1] TRUE
```

Why is `y` a vector? `n1` is numeric, `n2` is character, `n3` is logical, `n4` is a function.

They are different, so why is `y` a vector? Surely `y` can only be a list?

```
> data
name sex age height
1 x1 F 18 162
2 x2 M 19 170
3 x3 M 21 178
4 x4 F 22 166
5 x5 F 23 165
> data[1,]
name sex age height
1 x1 F 18 162
> is.vector(data[1,])
[1] FALSE
```

i am confused by vector ,why here data[1,] can not be a vectort?

Comment: Can you tell us why you are asking so many questions about "vector"? I've written thousands of lines of R code and I can't remember ever having to test is.vector(something).

Comment: i can't understand the concept vector and it's  usage.

Answer (score 10):

You are using `list` which create a *generic vector*. Lists can contain different kind of objects, and are themselves *vectors*.

Thus `is.vector` gives the right answer. See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#List-objects) for further information.

Moreover if you type `fix(y)` you will see the structure:

```
structure(
 list(
  n1 = 1,
  n2 = "qwe",
  n3 = TRUE,
  n4 = function(z){z+1}
 ),
 .Names = c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")
)
```

Answer (score 4):

`y` *is* a list:

```
> is.list(y)
[1] TRUE
```

You're confused because lists are vectors, which is described in the second paragraph of the Details section of `?is.vector`.  The same sentence says `is.vector` will also return `TRUE` for expressions:

```
> is.vector(as.expression(y))
[1] TRUE
```