# R - cannot select the desired element in a vector

Tags: r, vector, sum, netlogo

I have a vector of data called `empl` which I extracted from a NetLogo model using RNetLogo and whose entries look like

```
[[1403]]
[1] 99

[[1404]]
[1] 97

[[1405]]
[1] 95

[[1406]]
[1] 95

[[1407]]
[1] 95

[[1408]]
[1] 97
```

I would like to perform simple operation on the last numbers of the vector's entries (the 95,97,...).

Now if I write something like

```
empl[731] + empl[890]
```

I get

```
Error in empl[i] + empl[j] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If I understand correctly, this is due the fact that `empl[i]` does not pick the last number in the corresponding entry but rather the whole entry for instance

```
[[1408]]
    [1] 97
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to get the last number only. I tried

```
empl[1,i]
```

and

```
empl[i,1]
```

but got

```
Error in empl[1, i] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any help on how to select the last number only would be much appreciated. If someone can emply understand the structure of the vector `empl` that would be even better.

Comment: Might seem a little odd to flag my own question as possible duplicate, but I found the possible duplicate only after asking the question. I wanted to delete my own question, but got a warning message indicating it was not good practice. I guess it is better to leave the community decide whether it is worth keeping the two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `empl` object is not a `vector`. It is a `list`. A `list` object is formed by elements which can be arbitrary R objects. When you print a `list` and see:

```
    [[1403]]
    [1] 99
```

it means that the 1403rd element of this list is a `vector` with just one value (99). You select an element of a list through the double square bracket (`[[`) operator. So, if you try:

```
    empl[[731]] + empl[[890]]
```

you won't receive any error. I suggest to read [the R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing), and in particular sections 2.1 (which describes object types) and 3.4 (when indexing is discussed).

Comment: Thanks very clear and helpful. Thanks for the link too. Somehow I got tricked by the fact that is.vector(empl) reports TRUE, but should have dig a little deeper, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597175/why-the-object-is-vector.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `empl` is a list

You could do

```
Reduce(`+`,tail(empl,2))
```

to get the sum of last 2 elements

If you need to `sum` some specific elements for example `731`, `752`, `834`

```
 Reduce(`+`,empl[c(731, 752, 834)])
 #[1] 812
```

Or

```
sum(unlist(tail(empl,2)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
empl <- replicate(1000,list(sample(1:950,1,replace=TRUE)))
```